# Creating Automatic application updater in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services, auto-update

I have a windows application (lets say it "App A") which contains some windows services and a window form.

Now I am creating another application (name it "App B") which contains a windows service. This will check on my server if a newer version of "App A" is available or not. If newer version is available it will

download the new version --> uninstall the "App A" --> install new version

For uninstall I am using this code :

```
private void uninstall()
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\msiexec.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/x \"c:\\AppA.msi\" /qn";
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
```

For install I am using this code :

```
private void install()
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\msiexec.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i \"c:\\AppA.msi\" /qn";
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
```

But this code is not working and application is not uninstalled.

Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong. Its really very urgent.

Comment: I guess one solution could be using dynamic binding/reflection using which you can bind your assembly dynamically, if I'm not mistaken....

Comment: Have you got any more information than "not working": any error messages, logs, etc?

Comment: why is your packet's name is c:\\AppA.msi\ and not c:\\AppA.msi ? (dir or file)

Comment: Same question as Lonli from me, also when I have been doing MSI uninstalls using the GUID there is not normally a space between /x and the file|uid:
    MSIEXEC.exe /q /norestart /x"C:\myapp.msi"

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli I think that's just an escaped " character.

Comment: yep) you must be right. that's why I like @ symbol

Comment: Just a thought, why don't you use ClickOnce?

Comment: @Maheep I don't know how to use ClickOnce. Also I want my application to get updated automatically even if no user is logged in to the system. My application will be installed on Windows Server 2008 R2 VPS and it must update as soon as there is any update available. Will ClickOnce do this for me?

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli I thing @ symbol will not work if you want to add double quotes (") in the string..

Answer (score 1):

To help troubleshoot why this is happening i would do 2 things, first change the uninstall code to:

```
private void uninstall()
{
    Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Windows\System32\MSIEXEC.EXE /l* ""AppAUninstall.log"" /q /norestart /x""C:\MyApp.msi""";
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
}
```

This code will leave a file called AppAUninstall.log which will tell you the output of the msi uninstall, this could have info as to why its not uninstalling

Also, you have the quiet argument, /q, on there. Most of the time an MSI will need to be elevated with UAC on windows vista and above when run, so if you're updater application is not running as administrator then this will quietly fail.

Martyn

Comment: Can you please tell me where this "AppAUninstall.log" will be created?

Comment: it should be in your appplication directory. If you cannot find it, then you can use: @"C:\Windows\System32\MSIEXEC.EXE /l* ""c:\AppAUninstall.log"" /q /norestart /x""C:\MyApp.msi"""; that will put it on the root of C drive

Comment: I tried this method but this will not work because I am running this code in windows service and when service runs on any server and no one is loggedin then these type of operation will not work. Because for installation and instillation we need a user permission who has these privileges.

Comment: If the service is running as SYSTEM then it will have the highest privileges and should be able to uninstall with no user input.

Comment: but it is actually not doing that.. that is why I assume this... It just starts the process but did nothing. Please help me if you know the solution...